# Implement a retweet/reshare functionality using Parse

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform, structure

I've been stuck on this topic for awhile now, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Here's the setup: User A is following user B, but not user C. User B reshares a post from user C. The reshared post now shows up in user A's feed as the original post from user C and reshared by user B.

Really confused on what the structure of this looks like. I'm using Parse so it's safe to assume that I have the standard Users class and a Posts class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a reference column to your Posts class that can hold a reference to another post.  When user B re-shares the post you create a new entry in the Posts class that contains the reference to the original post but is listed as a post from B.

Now when you retrieve the posts that A is subscribed too, you will get the "repost" - you need to follow the reference to get the original content from C.  If you allow re-posts of re-posts then you may need to repeat this de-referencing until you get to the original post.