# parse.com 'retweet' pattern is too verbose

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, parse-platform

So, I have been tasked with implementing a *'retweet'-like* functionality in an app (*iOS, Swift*), using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/).

This has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603450/implement-a-retweet-reshare-functionality-using-parse), but that's a) pretty high-level and b) I get the task at hand - I am not necessarily asking for help on the architectural decisions, though if it seems that I am obviously missing something, I'm happy to accept feedback.

My app has CAUSES which are each created by a USER.
There is also a FOLLOW table with a TO and a FROM user.
So to start, I simply query the CAUSES table, with the constraint that the USER who posted should match the objectId of a TO user (where the current user is the FROM user) in the FOLLOW table. More succinctly:

```
let getFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: Constants.kParseClassFollowers)
getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey(Constants.kParseFieldFromUser, equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

let causesQuery = PFQuery(className: Constants.kParseClassCauses)
causesQuery.whereKey(Constants.kParseFieldFromUser, matchesKey: Constants.kParseFieldToUser, inQuery: getFollowedUsersQuery)
causesQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    if let causes = objects {
        for cause in causes {
          // populate the tableview cells, etc.
        }
    }
})
```

Now I have all the causes from users that i follow... that's all pretty standard.

Here's where it gets tricky.
Each CAUSE also has a Relation called SUPPORTERS.
Now I need to architect a way to get all the CAUSES from people that I do not follow, but which have in their list of supporters a user that I follow.

I have yet to find an elegant solution, though I am approaching a 'brute force' one, and it is so cumbersome and verbose that the better half of my programmer's brain is [screaming at me like Susan Powter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur0g-R7ZODY)...

Here's a sample:

```
let retweetQuery = PFQuery(className: Constants.kParseClassCauses)
retweetQuery.orderByDescending(Constants.kParseFieldCreatedAt)
retweetQuery.whereKey(Constants.kParseFieldFromUser, notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
retweetQuery.whereKey(Constants.kParseFieldFromUser, doesNotMatchKey: Constants.kParseFieldToUser, inQuery: getFollowedUsersQuery)
retweetQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    if let causes = objects {
        for cause in causes {
            let supporterRelations = cause.relationForKey(Constants.kParseClassSupporters)
            let supporterQuery = supporterRelations.query()
            supporterQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (supporters, error) in
                if(error == nil && supporters?.count > 0) {
                    for supporter in supporters! {
                        let user:PFUser = supporter as! PFUser
                        getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey(Constants.kParseFieldToUser, equalTo: user)
                        getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey(Constants.kParseFieldFromUser, equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
                        getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results, error) -> Void in
                            if(error == nil && results?.count > 0) {
                                for result in results! {
                                    // do stuff
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Now, this is pure madness, and incredibly wasteful (especially considering how Parse calculates the free tier - I feel this could really contribute heavily to my API limit if pushed to production).

Having already done two queries, I redo one entirely, then perform another query *for each cause* on the SUPPORTER Relations, then do another query on *each user* in that Relation to see if I follow them... and once I have that information, I need to loop through that User's supported causes (because of the asynchronous returning of the Parse queries, I don't feel that I can just reach back into the parent loops at all) ... which I haven't implemented yet, cause I'm about to throw in the towel - ***there has to be a better way!***

I hope that I'm missing a strategy here...

Comment: Seems to me you need a backlink from supporters to causes, no?  In which case, I'd recommend a linking table of USERS to CAUSES of which they are on the SUPPORTERS list.  Then it's just two queries -- get all of my FOLLOWERS, and then get the causes on which each USER is a SUPPORTER, and then weed out the duplicate causes.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense... I will explore that as an option.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework, but without changing the semantics, you can make the syntax a bit simpler.  I usually write `if let x = y { for i in x { ...` as `for i in y ?? [] { ...`.  I'd also consider replacing `if error == nil ...` with `guard error != nil else { return }`.  Those two won't save you lines, but they do save you columns: this would reduce your innermost `// do stuff` from 9 levels of indentation to 6, which is not *quite* as crazy.

Comment: you need to be using PubNub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jesses.co.tt I'm sorry if this is too little too late, I definitely take note that I am answering this months after it was asked, but I do think this is worth answering in general (and maybe could still be of value to you).

In general, I 100% agree that that triple query with Parse is a) going to be massively inefficient the way it's billed (in the old system) and b) with that in mind, seems like the wrong approach even with self-hosted Parse (which contextually is the only mechanism usable at this point since Parse has now shut down, but I think would still have been up possibly when question was asked...regardless...). There's 2 solutions I see that can fix this in a fairly clean way, assuming these changes can be made to the general schema/architecture.

**1)**
A first solution is to re-schematize the data set and essentially "foreign key" the subset of supporters each `User` has in the `User` table itself. This way, instead of going from `Cause`->`Supporter`->`User`, you'd theoretically be able to do `Cause`->`User` (where from users, you'd get their supporters by default as it'd be a column there). To do this in **`Parse`**, if I remember correctly you can set a column to have an array of a certain type as it's value, and then have `object` links there (that show up nicely in the Parse dashboard) that are actual `Supporter` table objects, but maintaining this column of links to that table in your `User` table.

While is a bit more work on the *`write`* side, since you'll have to manually do that (by manually I mean *write* the code yourself to do that, it should be automated but it won't happen for free in terms of development). With this slightly more upfront *`write`* operation, you then have a 2 step *`read`* instead of 3.

**2)** A second solution is to use a different provider for this kind of data, if query speed is an issue. In several of my projects I use socket based approaches for this kind of data query lookup, and thinks like **[Pusher](https://pusher.com/)** or **[Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com)** (both very different levels of "all inclusiveness", **[Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com)** being much more like a Parse but from *Google* this time, **[Pusher](https://pusher.com/)** being a bit more basic and "DIY").

With **[Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com)**, for example, and a socket to this data set + a schema in which the `Cause` table itself has a cache of what `User`s belong to them (and in which `User` has a cache of their `Supporter`s), this 3 step look up could effectively be 1 query with 2 parameters (which is I think the ideal scenario). I believe this can be achieved with Parse as well, but would require another step of schema refactoring to the first proposed solution.

I think in the comments something similar to this is recommended (both above solutions) but in a much more un-elaborated format. I hope this helps the original question-asker or someone. This could also, theoretically, as someone recommended, use **[PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/)** as 1 comment mentioned, but it could just as easily build this schema into a *PostgreSQL* DB hosted on AWS or *[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)* and accomplish the exact same mechanisms as Parse without the overhead.

Also, since this is in reference to Parse which is now only offered as an Open Source self hosted solution, here's a guide to migrate to hosting Parse on one's own on AWS: [link here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/resources-for-migrating-parse-applications-to-aws/)

Comment: Great answer, will revisit soon! Thanks!